# Filter user from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple chat, and I want to show the user only these chats to which he is subscribed.

The database is on Firebase, and the Frontend is React.

First, I add all rooms to room state, and this is saving ok. Then I want to filter these rooms to find only rooms with the user name.

Here I have a problem: I want to save all room with its data (message, name, other users) to new state `userRooms`.

I have tried different ways, but none of them works.

Docs in db:

```js
    collection (rooms) -> docs (name, users<Array>, messages)
```

The variable `user.displayName` is a variable with name user from context API after the user signs in.

Code:

```js
    const Sidebar = () => {
      const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([])
      const [userRooms, setUserRooms] = useState([])
      const [{ user, active, color, usersList }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = db.collection('rooms').onSnapshot(snapshot => (
          setRooms(
            snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
              id: doc.id,
              name: doc.data().name,
              users: doc.data().users
            }))
          )
        ))
    
        return () => {
          unsubscribe();
        };
      }, [])
      // try with map and filter
      useEffect(() => {
        rooms.map(room => {
          room.users.filter(item => item === user.displayName)
          return setUserRooms({
            ...userRooms,
            room
          }) 
        }
        )
       }, [rooms])
       // try with filter from filter here room in setUserRooms is unknown
       useEffect(() => {
        rooms.filter(room => room.users.filter(item => item === user.displayName))
         .map(
           setUserRooms({...userRooms, room})
         )
       }, [rooms])
       
       // try with includes but show includes is undefined
       useEffect(() => {
        rooms.filter(room => room.users.includes(user.displayName) && setUserRooms(...userRooms, room))
       }, [rooms])
       // check with if but it even doesn't work
      useEffect(() => {
       rooms.filter(room => {
         if(room.users === user.displayName) setUserRooms(prev => [...prev, room])
        })
      }, [rooms])
```